android can't get proper string resources for US
i have two string files in the project:
values -> strings.xml

values-en-rUS -> strings.xml

what i want to do is that if the language of the phone is English(US) then I want to show string resources in values-en-rUS. but somehow its falling back to values/strings.xml even the language of phone is English(US).
can't fix that issue for a long while. do you guys know any solution for that or is it a known bug?
